# Let $\phi:G \to (\mathbb{Z}/(15),+)$ be a surjective homomorphism. Then, $G$ has normal subgroups of indices $3$ and $5.$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

May I verify if my proof is correct? Thank you.

Let $\phi:G \to (\mathbb{Z}/(15),+)$ be a surjective homomorphism. Then, $\exists H_1 \lhd G, H_2 \lhd G$ such that $|G:H_1|=3$ and $|G:H_2|=5.$

Proof: By $1$st Isomorphism theorem, $\exists$ isomorphism  $f: G/ Ker(\phi) \to \mathbb{Z}/(15).$

Since $(\mathbb{Z}/(15),+)$ is cyclic, $\exists !H' \leq (\mathbb{Z}/(15),+)$ and $\exists !H'' \leq (\mathbb{Z}/(15),+)$ such that $|H'|=3$ and $|H''|=5.$ Let $H' = \{[0]_{15},[3]_{15},[5]_{15}\}$ and $H'' = \{[0]_{15},[3]_{15}, [6]_{15},[9]_{15},[12]_{15}\},$ then $H_1 \lhd G$ and $H_2 \lhd G.$

Clearly, $f^{-1} \restriction H' \to f^{-1}(H')$ and $f^{-1} \restriction H'' \to f^{-1}(H'')$ are isomorphisms. It follows that $f^{-1}(H') \lhd G/Ker(\phi)$ and $f^{-1}(H'') \lhd G/Ker(\phi).$

By Correspondence theorem, $\exists H_1\lhd G$ and $\exists H_2 \lhd G$  such that $f^{-1}(H')=H_1/Ker(\phi)$ and $f^{-1}(H'')=H_2/Ker(\phi).$ By $3$rd Isomorphism theorem, $G/H_1 \cong (G/Ker(\phi))/(H_1/Ker(\phi))\cong \mathbb{Z}/(15) / (H_1/Ker(\phi)),$ whence $|G/H_1|= \frac{|\mathbb{Z}/(15)|}{|H_1/Ker(\phi)|}=\frac{15}{3}=5,$  Similarly, $|G/H_2|=3.$

Comment: Im confused by last line of your proof. You showed $|G/H_1|=5$ but why this means that $|H_1|=3$? Its not true that $|G|=15$.

Comment: If you take $Z_{15}\oplus Z_{15}\rightarrow Z_{15}$ projection on first coordinate then your construction wont work.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Yes, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Now its correct.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the awesome Correspondence Theorem?

**Correspondence Theorem:** Let $\;\phi: G\to H\;$ be a homomorphism of groups. Then there exists a one-to-one correspondence between the subgroups of $\;G/\ker\phi\le H\;$ and the subgroups of $\;G\;$ *containing* $\;N:=\ker\phi\;$, and this correspondence respects normality and index of subgroups, meaning:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\forall\;\overline K\le G/N\;\exists!\,K\le G\;\;s.t.\;\;N\le K\;\;and\;\;\overline K=K/N\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;[G/N:K/N]=[G:K]\\{}\\\bullet&\;\;K/N\lhd G/N\iff K\lhd G\end{align*}$$

Your question's answer follows at once from the above.

Comment: Which is exactly what the OP is using.

Comment: Perhaps so, @egreg, but then what all those awful signs and calculations for?!